# VM Manager - OS Policy Assignment for a Windows VM in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, windows-server

I am trying to create a couple of **os policy assignments** to configure - run some scripts with PowerShell - and install some security agents on a Windows VM (Windows Server 2022), by using the VM Manager. I am following the [official Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management/working-with-os-policies#example-4) to setup the os policies. The VM Manager is already enabled, nevertheless I have difficulties creating the appropriate **.yaml** file which is required for the policy assignment since I haven't found any detailed examples.

Related topics I have found:

- Google documentation offers a very simple example of installing an .msi file - [Example OS policies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management/working-with-os-policies#example_os_policies).
- An example of a fixed policy assignment in Terraform registry - [google_os_config_os_policy_assignment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/os_config_os_policy_assignment#output_file_path), from where I managed to better comprehend the required structure for the .yaml file even though it is in a .json format.
- Few examples provided at GCP GitHub repository ([OSPolicyAssignments](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/osconfig/tree/master/examples/OSPolicyAssignments)).
- OS Policy resources in JSON representation - [REST Resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1/projects.locations.osPolicyAssignments#resource), from where you can navigate to sample cases based on the selected resource.

But, it is still not very clear how to create the desired .yaml file. (ie. Copy some files, run a PowerShell script to perform an installation or an authentication). According to the Google documentation *pkg*, *repository*, *exec*, and *file* are the supported resource types.

Are there any more detailed examples I could use to understand what is needed? Have you already tried something similar?

**Update:** Adding an additional source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the OS Config agent is installed in your VM by running the below command in PowerShell:

```
PowerShell Get-Service google_osconfig_agent
```

you should see an output like this:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  google_osconfig... Google OSConfig Agent
```

if the agent is not installed, refer to this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#agent-install).

2. [Set the metadata values](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#enable-metadata) to enable OSConfig agent with Cloud Shell command:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata $YOUR_VM_NAME \
  --metadata=enable-osconfig=TRUE
```

3. Generate an [OS policy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management/working-with-os-policies#os-policy) and [OS policy assignment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management/working-with-os-policies#example-policy-assignment) yaml file. As an example, I am generating an OS policy that installs a msi file retrieved from a GCS bucket, and an OS policy assignment to run it in all Windows VMs:

```
# An OS policy assignment to install a Windows MSI downloaded from a Google Cloud Storage bucket
# on all VMs running Windows Server OS.
osPolicies:
  - id: install-msi-policy
    mode: ENFORCEMENT
    resourceGroups:
      - resources:
          - id: install-msi
            pkg:
              desiredState: INSTALLED
              msi:
                source:
                  gcs:
                    bucket: <your_bucket_name>
                    object: chrome.msi
                    generation: 1656698823636455
instanceFilter:
  inventories:
    - osShortName: windows
rollout:
  disruptionBudget:
    fixed: 10
  minWaitDuration: 300s
```

Note: Every file has its own generation number, you can get it with the command `gsutil stat gs://<your_bucket_name>/<your_file_name>`.

4. Apply the policies created in the previous step using Cloud Shell command:

```
gcloud compute os-config os-policy-assignments create $POLICY_NAME --location=$YOUR_ZONE --file=/<your-file-path>/<your_file_name.yaml> --async
```

Refer to the [Examples of OS policy assignments](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management/working-with-os-policies#example-policy-assignment) for more scenarios, and check out [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/osconfig/blob/5eaa31e7da37f8e9bdf931ac411479f613eb6a54/examples/OSPolicyAssignments/gcloud/win-ensure-openssh.yaml) of a PowerShell script.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, and thank you a lot for your response. My main issue here is the lack of sample examples of .yaml files for windows. VM Manager is already set up and running and I have successfully created an OS Policy. However, it is not very straightforward how to proceed with a .yaml that: 1. deploy some agents, 2. add condition-based scripts etc. Some few examples are already provided like the one you mentioned above.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify what kind of agent you are trying to install; with the MSI example, the majority of them are covered. And for the condition-based script, the PowerShell example is very helpful as a base to create your own.

Comment: This is a good point. Basically, my aim is to: 
1.  Copy the necessary exe/msi/ps1 files to the VM. 
2.  Validate if the agent is running. 
3.  If not, enforce a Powershell script to deploy and configure the agent. 
The agents are coming with their own installation file, usually a .ps1 file. 

Using the "exec" - "validate/enforce" resource, I managed to trigger a PowerShell script that executes the local .ps1 file. So, essentially, I have figured out a .yaml file suitable for my case. Thank you! - @Gabriel

Comment: Good, so was the answer useful then?

Comment: In fact, the above provided related topics, bullets 3 and 4 (added recently) were very useful to form the desired .yaml file. GitHub repository provides an example for copying a file from a bucket and an example for executing a sample PowerShell script. @Gabriel

Comment: @TechEnth It's a best practice here on Stack Overflow to follow [these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when someone answers your question, I recommend you to take a look and follow them. We are a community and we help each other.

Answer (score 0):

Down below you can find the the .yaml file that worked, in my case. It copies a file, and executes a PowerShell command, so as to configure and deploy a sample  agent (*TrendMicro*) - again this is specifically for a Windows VM.

*.yaml* file:

```
id: trendmicro-windows-policy
mode: ENFORCEMENT
resourceGroups:
  - resources:
      - id: copy-exe-file
        file:
          path: C:/Program Files/TrendMicro_Windows.ps1
          state: CONTENTS_MATCH          
          permissions: '755'
          file:
            gcs:
              bucket: [your_bucket_name]
              generation: [your_generation_number] 
              object: Windows/TrendMicro/TrendMicro_Windows.ps1
      - id: validate-running
        exec:
          validate:
            interpreter: POWERSHELL
            script: |
              $service = Get-Service -Name 'ds_agent'
              if ($service.Status -eq 'Running') {exit 100} else {exit 101}
          enforce:
            interpreter: POWERSHELL
            script: |
              Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted','-File "C:\Program Files\TrendMicro_Windows.ps1"' -Verb RunAs
```

To elaborate a bit more, this *.yaml* file:

- **copy-exe-file:** It copies the necessary installation script from GCS to a specified location on the VM. Generation number can be easily found on "VERSION HISTORY" when you select the object on GCS.
- **validate-running:** This stage contains two different steps. On the *validate* it checks if the specific agent is up and running on the VM. If not, then it proceeds with the *enforce* step, where it executes the "TrendMicro_Windows.ps1" file with PowerShell. This .ps1 file downloads, configures and installs the agent. **Note 1:** This command is executed as Administrator and the full path of the file is specified. **Note 2:** Instead of *Start-Process **PowerShell*** a *Start-Process **pwsh*** can also be utilized. It was vital for one of my cases.

> Essentially, a PowerShell command can be directly run at the enforce
> step, nonetheless, I found it much easier to pass it first to a .ps1
> file, and then just run this file. There are some restriction with the
> .yaml file anywise.

**PS:** Passing ***osconfig-log-level*** - ***debug*** as a key-value pair as Metadata - directly to a VM or applied to all of them (Compute Engine > Setting - Metadata > EDIT > ADD ITEM) - provide some additional information and may help you on dealing with errors.